# Stack Exchange favorite tags filter

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, tag-filters

There is this nice page https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags where you can see an overview of all the questions in your favorite tags which is very nice if you are interested in many Stack Exchange communities. My problem is that Stack Overflow **really** dominates the list and it is kind of annoying. Creating a new filter is not that efficient since you'll have to add all the tags manually and of course, edit them when your preferences change.

It would be nice if you could create a new custom filter and have the option to include your favorite tags in the "I'd like to include..." section.

Comment: @Justastudent Intrestingly, the contact link in stackexchange.com (https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) gets you to https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact which in turn via the "visit our community here." link gets you here. I'll flag to migrate.